# Explain a confusing bound for the integral of a decreasing function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions, real-numbers

I am reading a solution of an exercise. In the solution, it says the following:

> Consider $g(x,t):=\frac{x}{(1+tx^{2})t^{\alpha}}$, where $x\in (0,\infty)$, $t=1,2,3,\cdots$ and $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$. Then, since for fixed $x$, $g(x,t)$ is decreasing in $t$, we must have $$\dfrac{x}{(1+(n+1)x^{2})(n+1)^{\alpha}}\leq\int_{n}^{n+1}g(x,t)dt\leq \dfrac{x}{(1+nx^{2})n^{\alpha}}.$$

I am really doubtful about this bound. Why is this true? This is basically claiming that for a decreasing function $g(x)$, it satisfies $$g(n+1)\leq \int_{n}^{n+1}g(x)dx\leq g(n).$$ How can we connect the area beneath the curve and the values of the function at two end points in such a way??

I cannot either understand or believe this... Thanks in advance for any explanation and confirmation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(x)$ is decreasing, for all $x \in [n, n+1]$, $g(n+1) \leq g(x) \leq g(n)$. Then we have $$g(n+1) = g(n+1) \int_{n}^{n+1} 1 dx  = \int_{n}^{n+1} g(n+1) dx \leq \int_{n}^{n+1} g(x) dx  \leq \int_{n}^{n+1} g(n) dx = g(n).$$

Comment: ah!! nice. thank you!!

Comment: we need to also assume $g(x)\geq 0$ in this interval. right? Everything else is perfect!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical We actually don't - monotonicity of the integral works regardless of the sign of the integrand.

Comment: oh. okay! thank you so much